# "Matches are on hold": because I need to complete something

Tags: bug, status-planned, stack-overflow-jobs, developer-story

I just put myself back on the market (another startup another layoff, yay) and got a note (via email) saying that my matches were on hold while I complete my developer story.

However, my profile *was* complete not too long ago and there's no indication that anything is missing now.

Help?

Comment: I'm looking into it, will get back to you soon!

Answer (score 37):

I've checked your email history to ascertain the source of that email and it was sent as a result of a nag email that is supposed to only be sent when your developer story is not minimally complete and when you are actively looking for a job.

It looks like we have a bug with a synchronization process that was triggered when you changed state from 'not looking' to 'active looking' and your developer story was picked up in that email batch.

So, apologies for the confusion and fear not; your developer story is perfectly fine and I'm looking into fixing the bug right now.